# Snap packages can't use my SSH key

Tags: ssh, snap

I have installed GitKraken, a git client, through snappy.

```
$ sudo snap install gitkrakren
```

But when I try to push to my repository, I get an authentication error. This was weird since I can make the push from the terminal without problems. So I went into the configuration and tried to manually set the public and private key. But when I tried to open the folder `~/.ssh` I got a message that it was forbidden.

- Could it be that GitKraken uses its own SSH keys, since it is a snap package?
- Is there a way to make it use my own keys or am I forced to use the SSH keys from the snap package?
- If it is the last case, where can I find them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is intentional that by default confined snaps cannot access your ssh keys (or indeed anything in hidden folders/files in your home directory) for good reason. You don't want a random application grabbing your keys and sending them to a remote server.

You can however copy all or some of your keys from `~/.ssh` into the home directory the snap sees under `~/snap/gitkraken/current/`

Comment: How can I copy them? I tried `cp ~/.ssh/* ~/snap/gitkraken/current` but it didnt seem to copy anything. Do I need sudo for this?

Comment: You got the command wrong: `cp -a ~/.ssh ~/snap/gitkraken/current/`

Comment: Makes sense, but is definitely a pain point. It seems like there should be a way to "trust" certain applications to have access to this. Copying the .ssh directory isn't a great solution, as then things can get out of sync.

Edit: Looks like this feature is coming: https://snapcraft.io/docs/ssh-keys-interface.

Answer (score -1):

Since there is a reason NOT to allow snaps to access your `.ssh` directly I would advice to copy only PUB key to a 'readable' folder.

I created a second `.sshpub` folder and copied over only the public keys to it, not the private ones.

```
mkdir ~/.sshpub
cp ~/.ssh/*.pub ~/.sshpub
```

Comment: Maybe, symbolic linking is better way in case if user's ssh keys would be changed in the future.

Comment: Presumably a git application would need the private key as well, to initiate connections to a remote server.